# Audiotoolbox API AudioConvertNewSpecific returning wrong output packet size when converting to G711u instead of AAC in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, audiotoolbox

I am trying to convert the RAW PCM buffers to G711u Codec in IOS using Audio Toolbox. I see many code examples working for the AAC codec using the same code and APIs.But when I try to do it for PCMU then it is not working. AudioConverter is setup with no errors but when I try to query the output packet size in AudioConverterGetProperty then it returns value of 2 which seems wrong to me because when I use same code for AAC codec then it returns output packet size of 600. Below here I paste my code and thanks in advance to help me out in this .

=====Source Code ===========

```
OSStatus result = 0;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription in = {0}, out = {0};

    in.mSampleRate = frequencyInHz;
    in.mChannelsPerFrame = channelCount;
    in.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    in.mFormatFlags =  kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    in.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    in.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    in.mBytesPerFrame = in.mBitsPerChannel * in.mChannelsPerFrame / 8;
    in.mBytesPerPacket = in.mFramesPerPacket*in.mBytesPerFrame;

    m_in = in;

    out.mFormatID = kAudioFormatULaw;
    out.mFormatFlags = 0;
    out.mFramesPerPacket = kSamplesPerFrame;
    out.mSampleRate = frequencyInHz;
    out.mChannelsPerFrame = channelCount;

    m_out = out;

    UInt32 outputBitrate = bitrate;
    UInt32 propSize = sizeof(outputBitrate);
    UInt32 outputPacketSize = 1024;

    const OSType subtype = kAudioFormatULaw;
    AudioClassDescription requestedCodecs[2] = {
        {
            kAudioEncoderComponentType,
            subtype,
            kAppleSoftwareAudioCodecManufacturer
        },
        {
            kAudioEncoderComponentType,
            subtype,
            kAppleHardwareAudioCodecManufacturer
        }
    };

    result = AudioConverterNewSpecific(&in, &out, 2, requestedCodecs, &m_audioConverter);
    if(result !=0) {
        DLog("Error AudioConverterNewSpecific %x \n", (int)result);

    }

    result = AudioConverterSetProperty(m_audioConverter, kAudioConverterEncodeBitRate, propSize, &outputBitrate);
    if(result !=0) {
        DLog("Error AudioConverterSetProperty %x \n", (int)result);
     }

    result = AudioConverterGetProperty(m_audioConverter, kAudioConverterPropertyMaximumOutputPacketSize, &propSize, &outputPacketSize);
    if(result !=0) {
        DLog("Error AudioConverterGetProperty %x \n", (int)result);

    }
    DLog("The output packet size is %x \n", (int)outputPacketSize);
```

======Output============

Error AudioConverterSetProperty 70726f70

The output packet size is 2

The problem is that the output packet size is returned to 2 and when I try to use the encoder then it gives me the output in 2 bytes for each call. I think we are not receiving the correct output packet size . How to correct it?

Comment: Have anybody used AudioToolBox AudioConverterNewSpecific API to convert RAW PCM frames to PMCU/ PCMA codec. I want to achieve same thing by above code, as there is no response on it till now so it confuses me if I am on correct path or not.